# How can I get RubyGems 1.3.6 on Ubuntu 10.4

Tags: rubygems

I've just installed a new vm (VirtualBox) with Ubuntu 10.4 and Ruby1.9.1. I've got the package for RUbyGems1.9.1 but when I do gem --version I still get 1.3.5.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I got it working using

```
gem install rubygems-update
cd /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin
sudo ./update_rubygems
```

Comment: you have a typo in the last line it should read: 'sudo ./update_rubygems'. Otherwise, thanks! This saved me a bunch of time

Comment: +1 Thanks, obviously works also with `cd /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin`

Comment: Confirming that this still works. 10.4 updated just fine using the above. Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

This no longer works.  It now gives the error message:
"Since apparently nobody reads my emails, blog posts or the README:

DO NOT UPDATE RUBYGEMS ON RUBY 1.9! See UPGRADING.rdoc for details."

It appears the only way to get beyond 1.3.5 on Ubuntu is to go outside apt-get and download the source.
http://blog.zenspider.com/2010/12/rubygems-141-has-been-released.html

Comment: link page is not available