# dev_appserver.rb cannot start after rubygems update on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, ubuntu-10.04

I had rubygems 1.3.5 (or 1.3.6?) installed and then made a `sudo gem update` after a long while again. Some gems complained they needed a newer gems version. Because `sudo gem update --system` is deactivated on Ubuntu I followed these steps: [How can I get RubyGems 1.3.6 on Ubuntu 10.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777831/how-can-i-get-rubygems-1-3-6-on-ubuntu-10-4)
But now I cannot start the `dev_appserver.rb` anymore, it says:

```
=> Bundling gems
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command bundle
```

I also tried to do `sudo gem update` and `sudo gem update --system` again a few times but everything is up-to-date now. Here is a list of my gems: http://pastebin.com/cFaTCyF5

Comment: Are you using ruby, or jruby?

Comment: Anyways, Rubygems 1.3.7 is, as far I know, the only version you can make work easily currently

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack around but I can't really tell what's going on properly from what you sent but I know a few people have been having problems after running gem update --system lately. Find out what version you've just installed with

```
gem list
```

Look for the update, should look something like this: rubygems-update-1.5.0

Then try rolling back your rubygems version

```
sudo gem uninstall rubygems-update -v 1.5.0
sudo gem install rubygems-update -v 1.4.2          <-- try a different version
```

Answer (score 1):

`gem install --system 1.3.7` worked in my case

Comment: depends on which appengine version you use... actually I know now several configurations that work, though all of them include using old versions of a lot of gems. (fixing the versions in the gemfile.) and one needs to uninstall this ubuntu gem-hack allowing to update rubygems with rubygems... still I hesitate to post my own answer, which is just a hack anyways...