# when i use bundle , Could not reach rubygems repository http://rubygems.org/

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
aoople@aoople:~/projects/jobs$ bundle
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not reach rubygems repository http://rubygems.org/
Could not find hoptoad_notifier-2.4.11 in any of the sources
```

somebody help me !

Comment: Are you working behind a proxy?

Comment: i use vmware and network connnection is Connected directly to the physical network.

Comment: So you are able to open the URL http://rubygems.org/ in your browser inside the VMware?

Comment: Check your current version of Rubygems  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777831/how-can-i-get-rubygems-1-3-6-on-ubuntu-10-4

Comment: perhaps at the same time you can try outside of bundler. namely just do `gem search -r hoptoad`. If that fails then try `ping rubygems.org`. In which case its a network issue. If it works, then maybe there's something more subtle going on.

Comment: my rebygems gem --version  is 1.3.7 . 
when i input gem install rubygems-update system show 
ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rubygems-update' (>= 0) in any repository .    
and i does't have /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin dir.

i going to find use $sudo find / -name gems
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/spec/install/gems
/home/aoople/ruby-1.9.2-p290/test/rubygems/gems
/home/aoople/ruby-1.9.2-p290/test/rubygems/gems/current/gems

Comment: hi matthew Ruby:
i try to ping rubygems.org it's ok.
when i use gem search -r hoptoad

aoople@aoople:~/ruby_gem$ gem search -r hoptoad

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/yaml)
what' problem ?